# Who did Ezekiel the Prophet resurrect?

Tags: talmud-gemara, yetziat-mitzrayim, resurrection-of-the-dead, ephraim

The Benai-Ephraim (Ephraimites) left Egypt many years before yetzias mitzrayim (the exodus from Egypt) happened. Unfortunately however they passed through Eretz Pelishtim (Philistine territory), and the Pelishtim killed them near Gaas.

However R' Yehuda ben B'sairah said that the people Yechezkel Hanavi (Ezekiel the Prophet) did  t'chias hamaisim (resurrection of the dead) on in the Valley of Dura in Bavel (Babylonia) were the Benai-Ephraim, and that he is a descendant of them.

If they were killed in Gaas, Eretz Pelishtim (Philistine territory) how could they have been revived in Dura, Bavel (Babylonia)?

Comment: A  source stating all of Shevet Ephraim was killed in the incident you describe would be extemely useful...

Comment: The relevant Gemara is Sanhedrin 92b. R’ Yehudah Ben Beseira just said that the incident actually happened; it was Rav who said they were the Bnei Ephraim.

Comment: To add to @DonielF's point, R' Yochanan (and a braisa) there say that this took place in the valley of Dura, but Rav can well be arguing on them and say that it was elsewhere (and that Hashem brought Yechezkel there).

Comment: Why does Sanhedrin 92b conclude that the bones in Yechezkel was Ephraim, when verse Yechezkel 37:11 states it is all the house of Israel?

11. Then He said to me, "Son of man, these bones are all the house of Israel.

Rashi:

Our Rabbis said (Sanh. 92b) that they were of the tribe of Ephraim, who left Egypt before the end [of the exile],

Comment: @sholomcohen How about [Rashi on v.11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.37.11?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he)'s explanation (in [translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16135/showrashi/true#v11)): "**these bones are all the house of Israel**: They are an intimation and an example of the entire house of Israel in their exile ... Another explanation: All of these were of Israel, and because you revived them now, they say,' Our hope is lost, and we shall not come to life once again when the dead are resurrected'".